Kommen oder Kommst
ist der Satz

Wie kommen du und Max dahin?

oder

Wie kommst du und Max dahin?

Ich meine, wenn eine Aufzählung vorliegt, wird dann "kommen" als 2. Person Singular konjugiert oder in 3. Person Plural?

Beides ist nicht richtig. Geht man nach der Duden-Grammatik (7. Auflage, Regel § 1602) aus der verlinkten Frage, so heißt es

(Kongruenzregel II für Subjekte mit gereihten Subjektteilen) 
a) Die Reihung gilt gesamt als Plural, das finite Verb steht daher ebenfalls im Plural.
b) Die 1. Person rangiert vor der 2. Person, und die 2. Person rangiert vor der 3. Person.

Also müsste theoretisch die Form

*Wie kommt du und Max dahin?

mit 2. Person Plural richtig sein.
Für mich klingt dieser Satz aber falsch*. Einige Kombinationen mit Aufzählungen mit "du" klingen nicht richtig. Was geht und was nicht, hängt vom Sprecher ab; daher würde ich Lernern empfehlen sie generell zu meiden. Stattdessen würde ich immer die Personen ansprechen, und dann mit "ihr" den Satz bilden:

Du und Max, wie kommt ihr dahin?

oder

Wir kommt ihr, du und Max, dahin?

Das ist nur um ein kurzes Wort länger, auf jeden Fall grammatikalisch, und löst die kognitive Dissonanz durch die Kombination von "du" (2.Person Sg) mit "kommt" (2. Person Pl).
*: nicht für alle, siehe Kommentare.

Falsch und ungrammatikalisch finde ich übertrieben. Dafür gibt es zu viele Belege.  Ein älterer: als du und Asdrubal in einem Bette laget. Ein jüngerer: dass du und Regine den Vortrag und die Diskussion nachvollziehen könnt. Wenn das Subjekt dem finiten Verb folgt, wirkt die 2. Person tatsächlich unangenehm. Sprecher können dann auf die 3. Person ausweichen, was im Duden auch erwähnt wird: Wie kommen du und Max ... (seltsamerweise finde ich wie seid du und Max ... gekommen aber besser als wie sind).

"Ungrammatikalisch" und "falsch" ist ein typischer Fall von "hier irrt Goethe".

Ich finde auch dass "wie kommt du und x da hin" falsch klingt. So wie hier formuliert ist das doch richtig ausgedrückt. Ob es wirklich falsch ist oder nicht, beeinflusst nicht die Wahrnehmung :-)
